# How do I know if I'm in human form?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I played Dark Souls 1 and found it practical to see at one glance if I'm in human form or not. The humanity counter in the top left corner indicated human form by shining in a brighter white than usual.

In Dark Souls 2 I can't figure out if I'm human or not unless I take of my helmet. My body is fully covered in armor so I can't see my skin condition.

Is there an indicator in Dark Souls 2 which displays my human form like in Dark Souls 1?

Comment: Could you please elaborate why you downvote so I can improve my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually very simple: 
**Check your health bar**

when you die in dark souls 2 , you lose health in the health bar.

So when your health bar is full you are human.

Comment: Is this assumption right? If I'm hollow I will never have a full health bar?

Comment: Yes, but you can still use bonfires and Levi up, wish couldn't in the first one. It's the game's way to punish you for death. There are many ways to alter this effect ( rings,... ), you will eventually discover them by playing

Comment: @Exa this isn't an "assumption". This is what happens. It's an inbuilt function in the game

Comment: 1. It also worth noting, that you can use Ring of the Dead to look like human even with not full health bar. But formally you'll be still hollow. not sure how this changes NPC interructions and other stuff.   2. ALso, I think human voice is different from hollow (the sound when you hit)